# Sort main rows while keeping sub order - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, html-table

I'm trying to figure out a good way to have a table which has sub data where we can sort on the main table without altering the sub data. Here's a MWE.

```
<table id="my-table">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th class="selectable">Num</th>
    </tr>
    <tr id="main-1" class="main">
        <td>Main 1</td>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="main-1 sub">
        <td>Sub 1</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="main-2" class="main">
        <td>Main 2</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="main-2 sub">
        <td>Sub 2</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

So you can kind of see I have 4 rows altogether, 2 rows that are "main" rows and 2 that are "sub" rows which are associated to certain "main" rows as can be seen through their classes.

What I'm looking to do is sort the table in such a way that *only* the main rows get sorted and the sub rows travel with the main rows. So if I sort by the second column I would have `Main 1 - Sub 1 - Main 2 - Sub 2` and if I reverse the sort I would have the order `Main 2 - Sub 2 - Main 1 - Sub 1`.

I tried using https://github.com/padolsey-archive/jquery.fn/tree/master/sortElements but this seems to do the entire table and I can't figure out how to make it move "groups" of rows together.

Any ideas?

(Note: the reason I'm doing the HTML structure as is, is because normally all ".sub" are hidden and when you click on ".main" it grabs the id and shows everything that has a class with that id. I'm open to changing the HTML structure if needed, and I don't mind either way if the sub elements get sorted too, I just prefer that they move *with* the main row)

This is the code I was using, but since it only does *every* line in the table, it's not really relevant:

```
$('.sub').toggle();
$('.main').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.' + $(this).attr('id')).toggle();                                                                                                  
});
var table = $('#my-table');
$('th.selectable')
    .wrapInner('<span title="sort this column"/>')
    .each(function(){
        var th = $(this),
        thIndex = th.index(),
        inverse = true;
        th.click(function(){
            table.find('td').filter(function(){
                return $(this).index() === thIndex;
            }).sortElements(function(a,b){
                a_num = parseInt($.text([a]))
                b_num = parseInt($.text([b]))
                if (a_num == b_num)
                    return 0;
                return a_num > b_num ?
                    inverse ? -1 : 1
                    : inverse ? 1 : -1;                                                                                                        
            }, function() {                                                                                                                    
                // parentNode is the element we want to move                                                                                   
                return this.parentNode;                                                                                                        
            });
        inverse = !inverse;                                                                                                                
        });                                                                                                                                    
    });
```

Comment: May you share the code you've used so far?

Comment: I added the jquery, sorry about that.